# Setting to fix Google Chrome tabs on a WQHD monitor

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, multiple-monitors

I have a Windows 7 laptop connected to a 27" WQHD monitor. Tabs in Chrome display correctly on the laptop, but on the high res monitor, they are unreadable. Tabs are perfect in Firefox and IE on both monitors.

I have tried turning off transparency for Windows 7, but the tabs were still unreadable on the high-res monitor in Chrome.

Here is a screenshot comparing the tabs on the laptop (left) and high-res monitor (right). What can I do to fix this issue?

[image: Unreadable tabs in Google Chrome]

Comment: chrome doesn't seam to be DPI aware: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=149881

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved this by applying a theme to Chrome. The tabs now have the proper contrast.

**1. Hamburger -> Settings**

**2. Get and apply a theme**

Now my tabs are readable.